# Is agriculture on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Agriculture, or at least horticulture, is a field that closely interacts with various fields of Earth Science such as soil science and meteorology.  Are questions about agriculture in general on-topic on Earth Science?

Consider for example, *[Disadvantages of various applications of technology in agriculture (Mechanisation)](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/10412/6)*.  This is not a very good question (does not show much research effort, could be a homework question), but do we otherwise consider it as on-topic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as questions with an agricultural element concern themselves with the earth sciences aspects of agriculture such as, but not limited to: soil science; meteorology, ground water; land use and its impact on the environment, whether it be local or more widespread, then such questions would be on topic.

However, when questions about agriculture are more about agricultural technologies and methodologies such as the best way to use heavy machinery or improving crop yields then such questions would be off topic.

Answer (score 5):

Fred captured my view as a hydrogeologist working in agriculture research. I would also consider plant breeding for yield or quality to be off topic, but breeding to respond to climate change or water stress, might be on topic in some cases. Questions regarding incorporation of earth-science into crop modelling would be on topic.